# How to dynamically add class to parent div of focused input field?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Below is my form.jsx file

```
var React = require('react');
var Input = require('./input');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            focus: false
        }
    },
    render: function () {
        return <div className="info_input">
            <div className="demo demo2 lll">
                  <div className={"css " + (this.state.focus ? "active" : "")}>
                    <label htmlFor="d3">{this.props.firstCol}</label>
                    <Input id="d3" type="text" handleFocus={this.addClass} handleBlur={this.removeClass} />
                  </div>
            </div>
                <div className="demo demo2">
                  <div className={"css " + (this.state.focus ? "active" : "")}>
                    <label htmlFor="d3">{this.props.secondCol}</label>
                    <Input id="d3" type="text" />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="clear"></div>
        </div>
    },
    addClass: function () {
            this.setState({
            focus: true
        });
    },
    removeClass: function () {
        this.setState({
            focus: false
        });
    }
});
```

and this is my Input component .jsx file

```
var React = require('react');

module.exports = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            focus: false
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return <input id={this.props.id} 
                      type={this.props.type} 
                      onFocus={this.props.handleFocus} 
                      onBlur={this.props.handleBlur} 
                      autofocus={this.state.focus} />
    }
});
```

If I focus on input field, it will add "active" className to its parent div.
However, all input field will also be added "active" class.

How can I do to only add class to parent div of focused input not all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have some simple logic (adding classes when focusing), it is a good idea to wrap this into a component and wrap this logic into it.

So, I've made a simple example:

https://jsfiddle.net/hLuv0c65/1/

It basically creates an Input component and adds `input--focused` to the parent div if the input is focused:

```
var Input = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
      return {
        isFocused: false
      };
    },

    onFocus: function() {
      this.setState({
        isFocused: true
      });
    },

    onBlur: function() {
      this.setState({
        isFocused: false
      });
    },

    render: function() {
      var classes = [];

      if(this.state.isFocused) {
        classes.push('input--focused');
      }

      return (
        <div className={classes.join(' ')}>
          <input
            type="text"
            onFocus={this.onFocus}
            onBlur={this.onBlur} />
        </div>
      );
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you @william-martins it helped me, but I would change your methods by only one: `toggleFocus() { this.setState({ isFocused: !this.state.isFocused }); }`

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be passing the id value to the addClass function and using this Id along with the focus check to determine if the class should change.

```
module.exports = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        focus: false
    }
},
render: function() {
    return <input id={this.props.id} 
                  type={this.props.type} 
                  onFocus={this.props.handleFocus.bind( null, this.props.id} 
                  onBlur={this.props.handleBlur} 
                  autofocus={this.state.focus} />
}
});
```

Another solution would be to separate your components.

```
module.exports = React.createClass({

 addClass: function () {
        this.setState({
        focus: true
    });
 }
 getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        focus: false
    }
 },
 render: function() {
    return (
       <div className={"css " + (this.state.focus ? "active" : "")}>
         <label htmlFor="d3">{this.props.firstCol}</label>
         <Input id="d3" type="text" handleFocus={this.addClass} handleBlur={this.removeClass} />
       </div>
   );
  }
 });

module.exports = React.createClass({
   render: function () {
     <div className="demo demo2 lll">
       <InputContainer />
     </div>
     <div className="demo demo2">
       <InputContainer />
     </div>
     <div className="clear"></div>
  }
 });
```